# Navigation Drawer icon is missing

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I can only swipe to open navigation drawer as my navigation drawer button is missing. I am using drawer layout for the nav view and co- ordinator layout for the bottom bar menu.

The code for the main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"


    android:id="@+id/dl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/baseLayout"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/default_activity_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"

        android:backgroundTint="@color/buttoncolor"
        app:menu="@menu/default_menu" />

    <!--status bar-->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/buttoncolor"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
        app:fabCradleMargin="6.2sp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="15sp"
        app:menu="@menu/app_bar_menu" />

    <!--add button-->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="#ED4444"
        android:onClick="openCamera"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"

        app:maxImageSize="35sp"
        app:tint="@color/white" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rw"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/empty_list" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty_list"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_icon"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_no_data" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Scan the files"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Scan to make something great"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"/>



    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, I think on default toolbar you have overlapped BottomAppBar (having android:id="@+id/default_activity_button") please remove that and check

Answer (score 0):

**I think  overlay BottomAppBar "default_activity_button" please remove and check**

```
 set navigation icon 


 set attributes  **app:navigationIcon**
```

**OR**

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

 toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_good);
 toolbar.setTitle("Title");
 toolbar.setSubtitle("Sub");
 toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```